# If $d=(m, n)$, with $m, n>0$, do $a, b$ integers exist such that $1=(\frac{m}{a}, \frac{n}{b})$ and $d=ab$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

I've been doodling around with some numbers and I think this is true, however I have not been able to prove it yet. I'd like to know if you have a suggestion or a counterexample for this. Thanks!

Comment: Choose $a=d, b=1$

Comment: If $m=12$ and $n=18$, then $d=6$. If I choose $a=d, b=1$, then $1\neq 2=(2, 18)=(\frac{m}{a}, \frac{n}{b})$. Moreover, if I choose $a=1, b=d$, then $1\neq 3=(12, 3)=(\frac{m}{a}, \frac{n}{b})$.

Comment: My oversight. In that case, one could consider the prime factorization of $m,n$ and choose $a,b$ to according to the exponent of each prime in the factorization.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, thanks for the suggestion. :)